# jquerymobile breaks rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I would like to create a mobile version of my rails 5.0.0.1 application using jquery mobile. 
As a starter I found useful instruction written in [a web page](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/23/a-better-way-to-add-mobile-pages-to-a-rails-site/) by Scott W. Bradley and in a railscasts [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices?autoplay=true).
However when I insert the jquery mobile js file in `app/assets/javascripts` and the jquery mobile css file in `app/assets/stylesheets` my application gets broken: css rules are not respected, redirects fails, javascripts do not work, colours are blurred, buttons do not work.

So I thought to add the jquery mobile files in a dedicated folder `/app/assets/jquerymobile` and I edited `/app/views_mobile/layouts/application.html.erb` adding in the head the following lines of code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/app/assets/jquerymobile/jquerymobile.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag '/app/assets/jquerymobile/jquerymobile.js' %>
```

However the files are not loaded, the mobile behaves as if the `jquerymobile.css` and `jquerymobile.js` files do not exist. My goal is to keep separated jquery mobile from the desktop version and load the files in case of request from mobile. However I would like to know what breaks the application, since the mobile version with the complete asset pipeline would inherit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To esclude css and js files from the asset pipeline it is necessary to add the following entries at the very end to `application.css` and `application.js`:

```
*= stub jquerymobile
//= stub jquerymobile
```

Then it is necessary to add the following lines of code in `/config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquerymobile.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquerymobile.js )
```

At this point it is possible to include the above css and js files using `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` in the head of the `/app/views_mobile/layouts/application.html.erb` file as follows:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquerymobile.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquerymobile.js' %>
```

See also this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ntamvl/00c55cad7524f1b3a8a3a09b08dd6908).